# Using multiple MQ servers in Java Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a Java Spring Boot application, and I need to send messages over IBM MQ and then listen for a response on a corresponding queue. I have a primary and (possibly multiple) fail-over MQ hosts. The queue names are different on each host (I have no control over this) so I need to have a different connection factory for each host.

I've looked at the mq-jms-spring code, and think I can adapt this to my needs. However, our current code, which works a comma separated list of hosts (and was written by someone else), creates both a connection factory and a transaction manager using that connection factory. It can use multiple hosts, but since the queue names are different for each host the fail-overs, well, fail. I'm assuming I need to create multiple transaction managers if I have multiple connection factories.

My questions are:

1. Do I need a transaction manager in this case?
2. If yes, then do I need a 1-1 relationship of connection factory to transaction manager?
3. If yes, how do I use the multiple transaction managers? I use the connection factory to write to the queue, but how do I notify spring which transaction factory to use? Does Spring automatically know this or is there some way I need to configure this?

Comment: Does your mq-jms-spring code use a CCDT?

Comment: I do not use a CCDT, and doubt that it's available to me.

Comment: Maybe the spring boot experts will correct me, but if you are using the java MQ client, then the option of a CCDT should be available to you.

Comment: [@kostellodon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12954463/kostellodon) did you get this setup and working?